# ksqlDB migrations tool HTTP2 Error when trying to apply migrations via ksqldb-cli docker image

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am trying to use ksqlDB migrations via a Github Actions file like so: https://github.com/jzaralim/ksqldb-migrations-action/blob/main/.github/actions/ksqldb-migrations-apply/action.yaml. When running my migrations I receive this error:

```
io.confluent.ksql.api.client.exception.KsqlClientException: Received 400 response from server: This endpoint is only available when using HTTP2. Error code: 40004.
```

does anyone have any insight on what could be causing this error? Is this a bug with the current version of ksqldb-server? I am using the latest version of both the CLI and ksqlDB Server (0.28.2)  The Initialize, Validate, And Dry Run options work just fine via this method. It is only when applying do I run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that our ELB was mutating our requests to all be HTTP 1.1 instead of HTTP2 so our ksqlDB server would not accept HTTP 1.1 requests since the endpoints that deal with migrations only accept HTTP2. This seems to be a bug on ELB that we have opened and issue with.